# EventListener doesn't pick up Event/ Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I'm pretty new to the framework and I'm trying to get a grasp of Event Emitters right now.

So what I'm trying to do and what should basically work:

I have this child class that wants to emit an event whenever it's data changes.

Implemented with:

```
@Output() docArrayChanged = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

and

```
onDocumentArrayChange(){
this.docArrayChanged.emit(this.documentArray)
console.log("onDocumentArrayChange Event emitted")
}
```

In my parent class I have:

```
recieveChangedDocumentArray($event){
this.documentList = $event
console.log("event recieved")};
```

and finally this HTML-Code in the Parents template:

```
<app-document-data
(docArrayChanged)="recieveChangedDocumentArray($event)">
</app-document-data>
```

According to my research this should do the trick, but i cant see the parents console message pop up, which should indicate the successful pick up of the event.

Edit:
imports in the emitting Class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Edit2:

Alright I got it working.
Previously i my child class called the "onDocumentArrayChange()" function in the constructor, to pass an array which got assembled there.
I did the same thing but in the "ngOnInit()" function, which turns out to make the whole thing work.
Im still not entirely sure, why that was the solution.
I suspect that its because ngOnInit() gets called earlier than the constructor.
If anyone got a clue, let me know.

Comment: How are you specifically importing [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)? Please update your question to show that.

Comment: If you aren't importing from `@angular/core`, then it would be the NodeJS [EventEmitter](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/globals.d.ts#L578) which would be the wrong one to use.

Comment: The one I imported is how it was described in the official documentation.

Comment: You see the message from the child in the console?

Comment: Nope, the message doesnt appear.

Comment: So, `onDocumentArrayChange` is not called?

Comment: Oh sorry, i misunderstood. onDocumentArrayChange gets called, just the parent console entry doesnt appear.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Maybe you can test a simple case and just emit a value in your child's ngOnInit method.

Comment: reverse the two lines in parent method and check if it console.logs. If no, it would be better you post some more of the code, specially evrything around documentList

Answer (score 0):

in order to simulate event listener in angular, you need two component. imagine you use the selector of child component in the parent component and you want to add event on the selector of child component. the steps you should follow in order:

1 - add @Output into child component.ts file.then you write the name of event and you should assign it with class of EventEmitter.

in child component :

```
          @Output change = new EventEmitter()
```

then in child component you have method, that in this method you should emit the event. imagine we have a star that with clicking on that, you make the empty star. Ok! no in child component we have:

```
     onClick(){
         this.change.emit();
           ///do other code

  }
```

then you can use the name of change, as an event on selector tag of child component in parent component.

in parent html :

```
      <child (change)="doSomeThing()"></child>
```

in parent ts file :

```
     doSomeThing(){

         console.log('i am in parent');
      }
```

now if you want to pass data, it is really simple. just go to child component, and pass the argument in emit method. now all subscriber of this event, can pass the data ;

in child component.ts

```
     onClick(){
         this.change.emit(arg);
           ///do other code

       }
```

now go to parent component.ts :

```
        doSomeThing(data){

         console.log('i am in parent' , data);
      }
```

last step:
go to parent html and as a parameter for event you should pass $event.

```
      <child (change)="doSomeThing($event)"></child>
```

in general,$event pass all condition about the DOM object, but here just pass data that it is set in parent component.

i hope it is useful for you.